# I am unable to find Django while creating a project in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I tried uninstalling and installing it and also tried with older versions but I still have same issues. I have manually created a virtual environment before and tried but didn't work but I can see that the Django is installed successfully on my computer. I tried to create virtual env from Pycharm and still have same issue. Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is Django installed in venv or globally? Have you tried to check _Inherit global site-packages_?

Comment: You are using PyCharm community which lacks Django support.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is fixed. I have  installed Django globally and created the project using existing interpreter in Pycharm.